# Loop through an array of multiple values

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following variable which holds an array :

```
$category = $request->get('catBox');
```

The variable has the following output :

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Zamalek" [1]=> string(4) "Ahly" }
```

How can I properly put the $category variable in the below query :

```
       $Tagids = DB::table('tags')
                    ->where('t_name', $category)                  
                    ->pluck('id');
```

So that after that I will loop through the result to store a row for each result :

```
foreach($Tagids as $tagid){

                      $tagIns = new tagpost();
                      $tagIns->tag_id = $tagid;
                       $tagIns->save();
                   }
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the content of the `$category` is it really an array? Add this ` dd($category);` after you get it from the request and make sure that it returns array of ids.

Comment: What does dd($request->all()) give you?

Comment: I made some changes to further clarify the issue

Comment: try `->whereIn('t_name', array_values($category))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use a `whereIn()` it accepts an array of values as second argument, i.e.:

```
$Tagids = DB::table('tags')
            ->whereIn('t_name', array_values($category))                  
            ->pluck('id');
```

Probably `array_values()` is redundant, you can try even without:

```
$Tagids = DB::table('tags')
            ->whereIn('t_name', $category)                  
            ->pluck('id');
```